# How to come up with research questions in statistical theory?

Tags: econometrics, mathematical-statistics, careers

(I think this question is appropriate as a community wiki?  If not, please close it, no hard feelings.)

Does anybody have links to webpages/PDF files of advice for grad students in statistical theory (or even better if econometric theory) trying to come up with good research questions?

I have been able to find such advice for medical researchers, computer scientists, applied economists, etc., but not theoretical statisticians (or econometricians).  (Other than asking professors in my department in person.)

There is a [corresponding CW on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451/advice-on-doing-mathematical-research).

Comment: Do not worry, econometricians will have good job markets in the foreseeable future, no matter what their dissertations are about. An average economist won't understand the subtleties of the regularity conditions necessary to derive the second order asymptotics :). But they would certainly know that their department needs a person to teach an econometrics sequence.

Comment: Short answer: Read a LOT of different papers and find those addressing topics that you'd like to spend several years reading a lot more about.  The longer answer is much the same, but with a lot of reasons why this is important.  It's much better to learn to read papers first, and to do so quickly & thoroughly, so that you can see the landscape and decide what's most stimulating.

Comment: From our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq): "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."  Therefore, regardless of what the MO folks might think, this question needs to be closed.  Bring it up on chat or contribute a blog entry!

Comment: @whuber "...what the MO folks might think..."?  MathOverflow?  :)  I, for one, do not lose sleep over what the MathOverflow folks may think.  Down, down with MathOverflow!  :)